# How to access Model.Something value in ASP MVC at View's javascript section

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to access a Model property value in ASP MVC at the View's javascript section

What is the best way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can't think of another way then just simpy printing it ;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJavaScripVar = '<%=Model.Property %>';
</script>
```

Comment: I'd also consider writing an extension method just to help clean things up a bit on your view, something that would look like <%=Html.JSVarFor(x=>x.Property, "myJavaScriptVar")%>

Comment: There's a potential security problem with this approach, if information shouldn't be publicly available. Client can see the infomration in the page source code. With ajax approach you can at least control the access to the data and e.g. detect web scraping.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an Ajax request to a controller method that returns a json result.