# How to read (MVC 3, Razor) model values from JS File?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm Have to ready models values in JS file for writing validation.. Is it Possible ?

This doesn't seems to work in JS file

```
var name = <%: Model.Name %>
```

Answer (score 4):

It will not work in js file, but you can write it in script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = '<%: Model.Name %>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I must point out that in your title you mention Razor, but in the question you use old school aspx syntax. So are you using Razor or webforms?

In any case, you should put your model into single quotes `'@Model.YourField'` or `'<% Model.YourField %>'` or very similar to this.

This way or the other, here is the successfully answered question that answers precisely your question:

[Accessing ASP.NET MVC Model Data from external Javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735665/accessing-asp-net-mvc-model-data-from-external-javascript-file)

Just in case, here is another example for you how to read `Model` values using old school style as you depicted in your question:

[How to access Model.Something value in ASP MVC at View's javascript section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618504/how-to-access-model-something-value-in-asp-mvc-at-views-javascript-section)

Hope this helps, please let me know if not.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a tag that its id is the name of your model:

```
<tag id='@Model.Name' class="test"></tag>
```

And in JS file you can get your model's name like the following:

```
var name=$("tag.test").attr("id");
```

Comment: But why dont you use from mvc validation instead of writing it?

Answer (score 0):

it may help full to you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var name = @Model.Name ;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently blogged about this topic: [Generating External JavaScript Files Using Partial Razor Views](http://blog.mariusschulz.com/2013/07/07/generating-external-javascript-files-using-partial-razor-views).

My solution is to use a custom attribute (`ExternalJavaScriptFileAttribute`) which renders a partial Razor view as is and then returns it without the surrounding `<script>` tags. That makes it a valid external JavaScript file.

Also, you might want to check out [6 ways of passing .NET server-side data to JavaScript](http://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/02/05/passing-net-server-side-data-to-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

you can put your model in hidden field(s) then read it in Js file